# Getting different date formats on local machine and in production

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I have a screen where I should search based on a particular date range.

When I try to search within the date range in my local host (connected to production database) I am getting the expected result. Whereas in the production (also connected to the same database) no search results has been found for the date range.

The problem that I found was that the date format in my local host looks like
`01-Feb-2018` whereas in production the date format is `01-febr.-2018`. I am sure the problem is here but not sure of how the format is changing for the production alone. I have changed the format of date in Java like:

```
if(packingMobileHdrTO.getFromDate() != null )
{
    fromDate = DATE_FORMATTER_DD_MMM_YYYY.format(packingMobileHdrTO.getFromDate());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The locale is set differently in prod vs your local machine.

Set them to the same, either:

- in your system's configuration
- on the command line when starting the JVM
- via a call to `Locale.setDefault(...)`
- or by setting the locale explicitly on `DATE_FORMATTER_DD_MMM_YYYY` (which is the most robust option, if the dates have to be in a specific format).

Comment: Thank you so much @ Andy Turner

Comment: Yes, I did. Both time zone and locale share the same problem of their current default being global to the JVM. Neither should be optional IMHO, as programmers all too often fail to consider them consciously. Thanks for the correction, I’ll re-post.

Comment: Beware of `Locale.serDefault` as it immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps within that JVM. Use only al a desperate last resort. Instead, pass the desired/expected Locale explicitly rather than relying implicitly on the current default. By the way, ditto for time zone.

Comment: @BasilBourque * `setDefault` ;) But yes.